# Python vectorizing a dataframe lookup table

Tags: vectorization, lookup

I have two dataframes. One is a lookup table consisting of key/value pairs.  The other is my main dataframe. The main dataframe has many more records than the lookup table. I need to construct a 'key' from existing columns in my main dataframe and then lookup a value matching that key in my lookup table.  Here they are:

```
lk = pd.DataFrame( { 'key': ['key10', 'key9'],'value': [100, 90]})
lk.set_index('key', inplace=True)

date_today = datetime.now()

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'date1':[date_today, date_today,date_today],
                 'year':[1999,2001,2003], 
                'month':[10,9,10],
                'code':[10,4,5],
                'date2':[None, date_today, None],
                'keyed_value': [0,0,0]})
```

This is how i get a value:
    df['constructed'] = "key" + df['month'].astype('str')

```
def getKeyValue(lk, k):
    return lk.loc[k, 'value']

print(getKeyValue(lk, df['constructed']))
```

Here are my issues:
1) I don't want to use iteration or apply methods.  My actual data is over 2 million rows and 200 columns.  It was really slow (over 2 minutes) with apply.  So i opted for an inner join and hence the need to created a new 'constructed' column.  After the join i drop the 'constructed' column.  The join has helped by bringing execution down to 48 seconds.  But there has to be faster way (i am hoping).

2) How do i vectorize this?  I don't know how to even approach it.  Is it even possible? I tried this but just got an error:
df['keyed_values'] = getKeyValue(lk, df['constructed'])

Any help or pointers is much appreciated.